# Get fax number or email address through the Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I need to get the fax number or email address of a list of restaurants through the Google Places API.  Is there a way to get them?  I can currently only get the address and phone number.

Comment: The title field is not meant for tags.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature.

There is a feature request for this in the Places API issue tracker here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3905

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently no way to access that data. You do get a link to the Place Page however.